# Getting the preprocessor to process a block of code

Tags: c, optimization, c-preprocessor

I have a system where I specify on the command line the verbosity level. In my functions I check against what was specified to determine if I enter a code block or not:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
if (verbose_get_bit(verbose_level_1)) {
    // arbitrary debugging/printing style code generally goes in here, e.g.:
    printf("I am printing this because it was specified and I am compiling debug build\n");
}
#endif
```

I'd like to make this less tedious to set up, so here's what I have so far:

```
// from "Verbose.h"
bool verbose_get_bit(verbose_group_name name); // verbose_group_name is an enum
#ifdef DEBUG
#define IF_VERBOSE_BIT_D(x) if (verbose_get_bit(x))
#else // not debug: desired behavior is the entire block that follows gets optimized out
#define IF_VERBOSE_BIT_D(x) if (0)
#endif // not debug
```

Now, I can do this:

```
IF_VERBOSE_BIT_D(verbose_GL_debug) {
    printf("I don't want the release build to execute any of this code");
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    // ... and so on
}
```

I like this because it looks like an if-statement, it functions as an if-statement, it's clear that it's a macro, and it does not get run in the release build.

I'd be reasonably sure that the code will get optimized out since it will be wrapped in a `if(false)` block but I would prefer it if there was some way I can get the preprocessor to actually throw the entire block away. Can it be done?

Comment: Please make it clear what (if anything) may vary in the statement beyond the argument to `verbose_get_bit`.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩: will this not work on C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it without wrapping the entire block in a macro.

But this might work for your purposes:

```
#if DEBUG
#define IF_VERBOSE_BIT_D(x) {x}
#else
#define IF_VERBOSE_BIT_D(x)
#endif

IF_VERBOSE_BIT_D(
    cout << "this is" << endl;
    cout << "in verbose" << endl;
    printf("Code = %d\n", 1);
)
```

Indeed the compiler should be able to optimize out an `if (0)`, but I often do something similar to this when the code inside the block will not compile at all when not in debug mode.

Comment: I was not aware that entire blocks may be used as macro arguments. What if a macro with multiple arguments is defined, and there are commas in the middle of a block sent to that macro? Regardless, this is definitely an option though quite strange looking.

Comment: It will actually still work even with commas somewhere in the block. Either way, you'll need to wrap it with `{}` if you want more than one statement.

Comment: So the preprocessor will keep track of scope according to `{}`? good  to know.

Comment: I just made another edit. Apparently, you can move the `{}` into the macro and it will *still* work. EDIT: I think this is as close as you can get to your if-statement as you can get - the only difference being the use of `()` instead of `{}`.

Comment: +1 because who'd ever thought this would actually work? Sounds too.. "good" to be true - no catches there?

Comment: I don't want to say that there are no catches at all, but at least I haven't found any yet...

Comment: Well it makes sense thinking about it: It's just strings for the preprocessor after all, so why would it distinguish between statements and whole blocks of code? I'll put that under "interesting to know" :)

Comment: This is definitely a good answer to my original question. I hadn't even considered the case of stuff in the block which would fail to compile which this does address. I'm sure that would come in handy.

Comment: Hmm. If a block has commas in it (such as declaring a series of ints like `int x,y,z;` It will screw up the macro (only the parts before the first comma get picked up for the macro block argument). I can work around this by avoiding commas in code.. Maybe there's a way around this?

Comment: You're right. It seems that it takes a `()` to correctly scope a comma in a way that works with the macro. I can't think of a work-around yet. (if there even is one) Since we're already abusing macros for uses they weren't intended for.

Answer (score 1):

Not anywhere near as neatly as you just did it. Don't worry, your compiler will fully optimize out any `if(0)` block.

You can if you so desire check this by writing a program in which you have it as you described and compiling it. If you then remove the `if(false)` blocks, it should compile to the exact same binary, as shown by an MD5 hash. But that's not necessary, I promise your compiler can figure it out!

Comment: Many compilers (including VC++) do _not_ produce byte-for-byte identical binaries from identical source upon repeated compilations.

Comment: True, but if you make the program as simple as possible it is more likely to.

Comment: At least in VC++'s case, even an empty `int main(){}` program is guaranteed not to.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a condition in the if-statement which is starts with "false &&" if you want to have it disabled entirely. Unless you compile without any optimization the compiler typically removes dead code.

Comment: I have definitely done this on many many occasions as a quick way to "comment out" some code.